# Complexity of calculating $(A^n)_{i,j}$

Tags: matrices, computational-complexity

I'm looking for the most efficient way to calculate a single entry of a matrix that was $n$ times multiplied with itself .

Pet example and motivation:
Let us denote the Stirling numbers of the second kind as 
$$
\left\{n\atop k\right\}
$$

As far as I know, there is no closed formula for $\left\{n\atop k\right\}$.

However, one formula for $\left\{n\atop k\right\}$ is the following:

Let 
$$
A:= \begin{pmatrix}
k & 1 &&&&\\
  & k-1 &1 &&&\\
  &   & \ddots & \ddots &&\\
&&&1&1\\
&&&&0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Then we have $\left\{n\atop k\right\} = (A^n)_{1,k+1}$.

---

Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{k\times k}$. I'm looking for the most efficient (exact or approximate) ways to calculate the cell $(i,j)$ of $A^n$ (further denoted as $(A^n)_{i,j}$).

Methods I've got so far:

1. Direct calculation:

By computing iteratively $A^i$ for all $i$'s that are powers of $2$ and then multiplying together all those appearing in the binary notation of $n$, we can calculate $A^n$ in $O(k^3 \log_2(n))$

2. Direct substitution:
   $$
   (A^1)_{i,j} = (A^1)_{i,j} \rightarrow O(1) \\
   (A^2)_{i,j} = \sum_{k=1}^n (A^1)_{i,k} (A^1)_{k,j} \rightarrow O(n) \\
   (A^3)_{i,j} = \sum_{k=1}^n (A^2)_{i,k} (A^2)_{k,j}
   =\sum_{k=1}^n 
   \left(\sum_{l=1}^n A_{i,l} A_{l,k} \right)  
   \left(\sum_{l=1}^n A_{k,l} A_{l,j} \right)
    \rightarrow O(n^2) \\
   $$

So at least for $n=1,2$ we have complexity significantly lower than by approach 1. Using memoization, the recursive algorithm admits the probably fastest elementary approach to the problem, though I doubt that it'll perform faster than $O(k^3 n)$ in the end.

3. Using the generating function:
   Discrete mathematics tells us that 
   $$f(x) = \sum_{n\ge 0}(A^n)_{i,j} x^n  = (-1)^{i+j}\frac{\det((I-Ax)^{(j,i)})}{\det(I-Ax)\qquad\,}$$

However, just calculating those characteristic polynomials is in $O(k^4)$ (and I don't know how expensive calculating $[x^n] f(x)$ actually is)

Comment: If you knew  the spectral decomposition of $A$ you can calculate the desired quantity easily, in $O(k)$ time and space.  But this is a big "if", and I don't know if the decomposition of _your_ $A$ is known.

Comment: @kimchilover It isn't known. I've looked a little into algorithms for calculating e.g. the Jordan-Normal-Form, and it seemed that there were problems with robustness